Can non-parents ask questions and on what conditions
Are non-parents allowed to ask questions in the main site and on what conditions?
I am asking a separete question instead of editting my latest question because I am afraid it could be considered an abuse of the system. I am not sure if it can be considered the same question (just reworded and shorter) or not. If this question is considered a duplicate then I would like to understand what exactly is a change in a question that has already been answered and what is a duplicate (in the Meta of Parenting.SE). What should one do when they already got answers but the question they asked probably ended up not being what they wanted to ask.
From the answers there I can't understand if I am allowed to ask questions.
The linked question was my first attempt at asking the question I actually had. The answers to it signal to me that it ended up miles away from what I actually intended to asked.
My intention was to ask whether non-parents were allowed to ask questions in the main site (and under which conditions).
I am reading the meta to try and find the answer but I can only find answers from 8 or even 12 years ago. I understand that the paradigm may have shifted.
Seeding (asking for the sake of asking) was actually not per se problematic (unless answerers were made to feel that the author doesn~t care about the answers).
Just because a question is hypothetical doesn't mean it is automatically a problem.
Hypothetical problems aren't de facto unwelcome if the OP sticks around to clarify and discuss,

Most of the post above doesn't make sense. What does "an actual problem you have faced" mean? It means, an actual problem you, yourself, have faced. Why is that confusing? What does "a real problem you've encountered" mean? It means a problem that you, yourself, have encountered. //  On the other hand, "I understand that if I question myself I have faced these real and actual problems" makes no sense at all to me. To my thinking, that means there is confusion regarding thoughts and reality. I think about a problem, therefore I have experienced it. Um, no. Apply that to racism or misogyny.

To answer your question directly, please allow me to repeat a comment here:

"Most of the post above doesn't make sense. What does "an actual problem you have faced" mean? It means, an actual problem you, yourself, have faced. Why is that confusing? What does "a real problem you've encountered" mean? It means a problem that you, yourself, have encountered. // On the other hand, "I understand that if I question myself I have faced these real and actual problems" makes no sense at all to me. To my thinking, that means there is confusion regarding thoughts and reality. I think about a problem, therefore I have experienced it. Um, no. Apply that to racism or misogyny.

If you are not a woman, you have never experienced, personally, misogyny. If you are not of a racial or ethnic minority that experiences widespread, systematic discrimination, you have not experienced racism. If you do not or have not cared for a child in any way in loco parentis, you have not experienced parenthood.
Someone once explained in an answer on Meta.SE that different sites on SE are like sandboxes. Just because two sandboxes exist doesn't mean that the kids at each sandbox are playing by the same rules.
Each site has its own set of "rules", also referred to as its "culture". With a bit of effort and some observation, users get to know them in time; if they get what they need from the site, they accept the rules. Some people who don't like the rules or the culture leave and look elsewhere for a better fit. Some people instead try to change the site. Sometimes it works, and a change is made, but this is pretty far the norm. What usually happens is that the user butts heads repeatedly, ad nauseum, with users and moderators trying to give guidance to the dissatisfied user. When the moderators feel that a repeated behavior that has been addressed sufficiently to have changed, but has not, suspensions ensue. Nota Bene: these aren't just moderator decisions; moderators respond to users' flags, a way for users to point out things that violate a site or network rule, e.g. being mean in comments, answering in comments, not supporting important points in an answer, etc. In that way, moderators respond to users' expectations of the site culture as well. Suspensions escalate in duration.
This is not a threat. You present yourself as someone who reads between the lines, as wondering if "conversational implicature" is occurring. It's not. In this post, I'm simply explaining what happens when rules are repeatedly violated, so that if you ever meet these circumstances personally, you will hopefully understand why they are happening.

Participation on this site is voluntary. I stated that though hypothetical questions are discouraged (especially the vague kind that you have been shown to ask), you can, as a non-parent, comment if you have something helpful to add, and you can answer questions (there are some non-parents active on this site) if you have something helpful to add. (Some people - not you - have left very unkind comments or answers, the worst recommending to physically damage the child or worse.) That does not contradict the fact that hypothetical questions are poorly met.
I have personally spent a fair amount of time trying to help and guide you, even if it doesn't feel that way to you. For this reason, I will not engage with you in comments questioning or disputing points in this post. My time left on this planet is limited, and I must use it in a manner which I see as beneficial to someone, be that myself or others. Apologies in advance.

The only sense that the question could make would be "What are the rules" particularly about a non-parent asking questions. Maybe I could make the question shorter "Are non-parents allowed to ask questions?" without reffering the tour at all.  But I referred to it because some comments felt like a reprehension. "Have you even read the tour".

Your last sentence is the key to the question:

I understand that if I question myself I have faced these real and actual problems.

This is incorrect. Thinking about a problem is not the same as experiencing a situation in real life. The former is always hypothetical and no matter how deeply you try to think, it’s not the same as a real life scenario. The level of complexity of real human behavior and interactions is very high. Any helpful advice must and will take into consideration as many of the specific aspects of the asker’s context as possible and needed.
A good answer will (often just subconsciously) employ methods from systemic thinking. Small differences and details can have a huge impact. That is one of the reasons why we insist on real life problems. And also a reason why users often ask for clarification when they feel they need more information to be able to answer in a meaningful way.
Real life means real humans (typically the asker) have a real scenario where they interact with other real humans (typically their children). Any deviation from this rule must still be based on a specific real life scenario, but can be for example future-oriented (“my child has the following personality traits, how can we help them start school later this year, considering these traits and habits” or past “a specific event or interaction went particularly bad, how can we avoid that in the future”.
Or put in the simplest way possible: if there is no real child and no real parent (equivalent) involved, it’s very likely off topic.

In my neighboorhood there is an Elementary School so whenever I go to University in the morning I see some children walking to Elementary School (they have a specific birthday which I don't know) I ask myself what should their specific parents do. There is a real child right in front of me and there is a real parent (supposedly they are not orphans).

But you are not living their lives, you are observing them from a distance. You have no idea what obligations and duties influence their decision-making, what experience shape their perception of the world, what fear or beliefs drive them. This will be different for each child & family involved. If you really struggle to understand this (and I’m giving you the benefit of the doubt big time here), then follow "Unless you have a problem with your kids or at least have a specific kid in mind don't ask questions" (your phrasing, not mine). This is not a place for purely mental exercises.

What I am stuggling to understand is how what you first said "You have no idea what obligations.......different for each child & family involved" is different from my words ""Unless you have a problem with your kids or at least have a specific kid in mind don't ask questions". In most questions here I don't see a list of obligations or duties. I don't see a list of experiences, fears or beliefs. This will be different for each child & family involved but this difference seems acceptable for Parenting.SE and the rest of those asking questions how is my situation any different from other people?

Try to learn to swim without going into the water, understand snow without having touched it. That’s the difference between being a parent and thinking about parenting. There will be no further discussion. If you fail to understand that difference, then we can’t and won’t explain further. For you, that means accept it as a rule (even if you don’t understand), or move on.

I do understand that there is a big difference between being a parent and thinking about parenting. I am trying to understand if there is some conversational implicature when you mention this difference. Depending on how deep we read between the lines mentioning the difference may imply "If you aren't a parent you aren't welcome in Parenting.SE". If so the tour could probably be reworded. Explicatures are clear Implicatures are not. If one isn't welcome unless they aren't a parent it would be helpful to have it spelled out, put into (clear, explicit, unambiguous) words.

@GeorgeNtoulos "...conversational implicature..."? There is no implicature; it is explicit: if you are not a parent, you cannot ask questions as if you were a parent. It does not imply anything else. You can comment, answer questions (there are some non-parents active on this site), and, if asking a hypothetical, you must understand that it will, the way YOU ask hypotheticals, likely be closed as off-topic. The words are unambiguous. You are reading into them in an attempt to build up your straw man.

"I do understand that there is a big difference between being a parent and thinking about parenting" (contradicts your last statement.) Stick with this new (and true) understanding, and please extend this understanding to include that there are real parents here looking for real answers to real problems, and there are real people with real experiences trying to help these real parents. That you will someday be a parent is immaterial. If you want that kind of guidance, there are lots of books about parenting. This site doesn't exist to support your vision of it. It is what it is.

The tour is perfectly fine as it is written.

@anongoodnurse I am certainly not asking questions as if I was a parent. 2 of your own quotes are contradictory "You can comment, answer questions (there are some non-parents active on this site)" and " If you want that kind of guidance, there are lots of books about parenting."

@anongoodnurse I am not a linguist but from what I read an implucature is like "Please open the door" when one is saying "The doorbell is ringing" or "Don't put the food on the table" when they are saying "The kids have not arrived yet". The meaning of most utterances is affected by the extralinguistic environment. When housemates tell you that the doorbell is ringing the meaning (what they want to convey with the utterance) doesn't exhaust itself in the explicature that the door's mechanism is making the characteristic sound. "I am taking a bath" then also means "I can't get the door".

@GeorgeNtoulos - Very true. My comment stands. Stephie was being direct.

@anongoodnurse Are you saying that"But you are not living their lives, you are observing them from a distance. You have no idea what obligations and duties influence their decision-making, what experience shape their perception of the world, what fear or beliefs drive them. This will be different for each child & family involved." means nothing more and there is no implicature? That would mean that the utterance is quite simple almost a truism (obvious/trivial). The explicature would be almost unnecessary on it's own. I'd need to be delusional not to understand the differences themselves.

@GeorgeNtoulos At times, I have actually wondered about that last statement. How would you know? Delusional people don't know they're delusional. They think they're rational. Are you deceiving yourself by believing outrageous things, or just pretending to believe them?

@anongoodnurse I didn't understand this last question.

@Stephie While I haven't been able to find any concise list of rules. I understand rules are for the question 1 to be answerable in a reasonable lenght (not a textbook but a couple of paragraphs) with supporting evidence 2 to be potentially useful for someone in a parenting role (parent, nanny, teacher, etc) 3 to have a civilized environment for participants to feel that their time is respected and valued (example that the author of the question cares about the effort spent by the author of the answer). Please correct me if I am wrong add something that I missed or change what I listed above.

@Stephie What is the conclusion drawn from the premise (with which I completely agree) "But you are not living their lives, you are observing them from a distance. You have no idea what obligations and duties influence their decision-making, what experience shape their perception of the world, what fear or beliefs drive them." I am not them. So What? Can't I post a question asking what should they have done (or even what should I do if I am ever in this specific situation or I am asked for advice)?

@anongoodnurse The implicature in "But you are not living their lives, you are observing them from a distance. You have no idea what obligations and duties influence their decision-making, what experience shape their perception of the world, what fear or beliefs drive them." The implicature would be "don't ask questions unless you are undertaking now a parenting role". Stephie didn't say anything about non-parents not asking questions. But I am questioning myself if there is any such conversational implicature (since there is no such explicature).

@GeorgeNtoulos Sorry, not interested. You can keep trying, though. Heh.
